# convexity of $g(x)^TAg(x)$, where $A$ is a $n\times n$ positive definite matrix, and $g$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ nondecreasing elementwise

Tags: convex-analysis, quadratic-forms

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^TAx$, where $x = (x_1, \cdots,x_n)^T$, and $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix (thus $f(x)$ is strictly convex). And suppose $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, $g(x) = (\exp(x_1), x_2, \dots,x_n)^T$. Is $$h(x) = f\circ g(x) = g(x)^TAg(x)$$
strictly convex?

---

I tried to use Hessian, but found Hessian is not positive definite. Thus I cannot use Hessian to prove strict convexity. Now, I am trying to use the definition to prove it, but I got stuck. I tried the simplest case where $A$ is two by two matrix
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{12} & a_{22}
\end{matrix}

and got $$h(x) = a_{11}\exp(2x_1)+2a_{12}\exp(x_1)x_2+a_{22}x_2^2$$
So at least it is strictly convex on each axis (marginally). But I am not able to show its strictly convexity jointly. Thanks!

Comment: a common approach would be to try differentiating twice and looking at the signature of the Hessian.  Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, @user8675309. However, the Hessian matrix is not positive definite. Thus, we cannot use Hessian to show its strict convexity.

Comment: That seems like something that belongs in your post

Comment: So to be clear, you've evaluated the Hessian to be PSD and confirmed the function is convex, and what remains is to confirm that said convexity is *strict*, correct?

Comment: Hi @user8675309, I found its Hessian is positive definite. If the Hessian is positive definite, then I can conclude that $h(x)$ is strictly convex. However, the Hessian is not positive definte :(

Comment: you just wrote "I found its Hessian is positive definite...  However, the Hessian is not positive definte."  This is a contradiction.  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I found its Hessian is not positive definite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
h(x) = e^{2x_1}a_{11} + 2\left(\sum_{i=2}^n a_{i1} e^{x_1}x_i \right)+ \left(\sum_{i,j=2}^n a_{ij} x_ix_j\right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2} h(x) = 4a_{11} e^{2x_1} + 2\sum_{i=2}^n a_{i1} e^{x_1}x_i .
$$
If one of the numbers $a_{i1}$ is non-zero then
set $x_j=0$ for $j\ne i$, $x_i > -\frac{4a_{11}}{a_{i1}}$.
For such $x$, we have $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2} h(x)<0$.

This implies that $h$ is not convex! If $h$ would have been convex, then $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2} h(x)\ge0$ for all $x$.